# Authentication Options with Google Gmail API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, gmail-api

Just getting started with Google Rest APIs, specifically the Gmail API. I am having trouble finding simple examples and answers.

Does the Google API for Gmail require Oauth2?...or can some combination of API Key and a service account be used? If we didn't have to use Oauth we wouldn't, but I can't find examples and the google docs aren't clear to me. Can I use a google service account to get an access token and use that in combination with my API key?

Comment: It depends on details such as Workspace or Gmail. What is accessing Gmail: users or backend services? Are you using Domain Wide Delegation? Which APIs are you using? Edit your post to clearly define a problem. Google provides documentation on Gmail Authorization. Example: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/web-server

Comment: Backend services would access this.

Problem: Look up a Gmail users profile using a rest API call, without using OAuth2, this that would be this endpoint: https://gmail.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{{userid}}/profile

That link you sent says at the top: 

Requests to the Gmail API must be authorized using OAuth 2.0 credentials.

So that may be the answer to my question...

Comment: There are several methods. Each has a drawback. Requesting a user's profile is not a problem (usually), reading their email is a problem that can result in a security audit for your app. Edit your question with the new details. Don't use comments.

Answer (score 2):

> Does the Google API for Gmail require Oauth2?

Gmail accesses private user data. In order to access private user data your app needs the permission of the owner of the data to access it.  For this we use Oauth2.

> or can some combination of API Key and a service account be used?

Api keys are only used to access public data. You can not access private user data using an api key.

Service accounts can be used with the gmail api if you configure domain wide deligation on your google workspace account. then your service account will be able to impersonate any user on the domain.

To be clear service accounts can not be used with standard google gmail accounts, it can only be used with a workspace domain account.

Comment: Thanks, I found some of your examples which were very helpful and my first tests are working. 

So I'd like to use Oauth2 and this is a server-to-server app...so no client interaction which I am currently stuck on....

Comment: if its workspace domain use a service account.    if its standard users request authorization store the refresh token the have the server use the refresh token to request a new Access token