# trying to connect to gmail api using a service account on nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

It is my first time using the gmail api. I am trying to use the gmail api via a service account. The goal of my program is to parse emails through my email only and to look for certain keywords and compare them to a local database. However I am unable to connect to the gmail api. I did do the steps of creating the service account, downloading the service account key json file and giving permission to domain wide delegation to the service account. I have also given the scope of https://mail.google.com/. I am simply trying to prove I can connect and the authentication works by doing a getprofile call.

```
const {google} = require('googleapis');

const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: './serviceaccountkey.json',
  scopes: ['https://mail.google.com/'],
  subject: 'admin@example.org',
});


const gmail1 = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth: auth});


async function temp1(){

  var cont = gmail1.users.getProfile({userId: "me",}) 
  return cont;
}

console.log(temp1());
```

This does not work as I return an error of precondition check failed.

```
           throw new common_1.GaxiosError(`Request failed with status code ${translatedResponse.status}`, opts, translatedResponse);
                      ^

GaxiosError: Precondition check failed.
    at Gaxios._request (C:\Users\user\Documents\FunctionAzure\node_modules\gaxios\build\src\gaxios.js:130:23)
```

the only code I get is 400 with message of precondition check failed.

I was expecting to see output for the get profile gmail api call. I have done some reading and my only guess is I need to do something with JWTs which I am confused about. Are JWTs and service account json file you download the same thing? I appreciate any insight anyone can offer, thank you

Comment: A service account JSON file contains an RSA private key. The private key is used to sign a JWT ( called an assertion). The signed JWT is exchanged via a Google endpoint for an OAuth access token. I don't think your problem is with the token because the HTTP status code is 400. That often means an incorrect request. Hopefully one of the node engineers will provide a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on how you're authenticating, I think you should directly request the gmail submodule which exposes ['auth'](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/main/src/apis/gmail/index.ts#L33) i.e. your code should be

```
// request the gmail module which exposes auth
const gmail = require('@googleapis/gmail') 

// provide information for authenticating
const auth = new gmail.auth.GoogleAuth({
  keyFile: './serviceaccountkey.json',
  scopes: ['https://mail.google.com/'],
  subject: 'admin@example.org',
});

// create an auth client
const authClient = await auth.getClient();

// authenticate to gmail and create a gmail client
const gmail1 = await gmail.gmail({
    version: 'v1',
    auth: authClient
});
```

See the example in their documentation [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) (look for the section - Alternatively, you can make calls directly to the APIs by installing a submodule)

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing and according to this thread
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76541774/authentication-options-with-google-gmail-api

It is not possible to access gmail using service account.
Did you had any luck with fetching email content without OAuth2?